# Deduce th inequality $c^n\ge c$ by using Bernoulli's Inequality

Tags: inequality

> Deduce $c^n\geq c$  for all $n\in\mathbb{N} $, $c>1$

What I have tried is: let $x=c-1$. 
Then I substitute it into the Bernoulli's inequality, that is
$$c^n\geq1+n(c-1)\geq 1+nc-n\geq nc+1$$

How can I complete the proof? Or is there something wrong for my idea?

Comment: Why use Bernoulli's inequality at all when plain induction is so much simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show: $1+nc-n \geq c$ ,which is $(n-1)(c-1) \geq 0$,is clearly true.